# How to access style.xml values

Tags: android

I have styles.xml with Style definition like this:

```
<style name="Style1">
    <item name="titleColor">@color/red</item>       
    <item name="lineColor">@color/light_red</item>
</style>
```

I'd like to access "titleColor", "lineColor" attributes values programmaticaly. Is it possible somehow to do? 
Would appreciate your help very much, cause already spend hours trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is here [how to get Theme attributes values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052549/how-to-get-theme-attributes-values)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do it like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Style1">
   <item name="titleColor">@color/red</item>       
   <item name="lineColor">@color/light_red</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then Build the Project, after Building you can access the values with

```
R.style.Style1...
```

edit to clarify:

```
button1.setBackgroundColor(R.style.Style1.titleColor);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I defined my problem differently: I need to access style values from java sources programmaticaly.

Comment: I fail seeing how to do that, in my R class, the style is just a "public static final int" variable

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use following code in order to access the style1,

```
style="@style1/titleColor"
style="@style1/lineColor"
```

That is all.

Comment: Sorry, but I defined my problem differently: I need to access style values from java sources programmaticaly.