# how to get Theme attributes values

Tags: android

Is it possible to obtain styled attributes values from particular Theme without setting the theme up to application/activity?
(I mean before invoking `context.setTheme(..)`)

Comment: For anyone interested I found the solution by myself :)

Comment: TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.ThemeName, new int[] {R.attr.attribute_name});

Comment: int attributeResourceId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);

Comment: Kid24, You can post an answer to your own question.  This is useful since then it shows up as an answered question.

Comment: thanks, I'll follow your advice, but later, cause  unfortunately - "New users can't answer their own question for 8 hours" :)

Comment: Don't forget `a.recycle()`!

Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252839/what-is-the-use-of-recycle-method-in-typedarray

Answer (score 49, accepted):

For example, to get editTextColor attribute's value of a theme called MyTheme:

```
TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
        R.style.MyTheme,
        new int[] { R.attr.editTextColor });

// Get color hex code (eg, #fff)
int intColor = a.getColor(0 /* index */, 0 /* defaultVal */);
String hexColor = Integer.toHexString(intColor);

// Don't forget to recycle
a.recycle();
```

Comment: ...and if you are looking for a way to also get the themes style  resource id dynamically see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9537629/317889

Comment: You should call [`a.recycle()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#recycle()) when you're done with the TypedArray.

Answer (score 2):

JavaDoc:

> method `TypedArray`
>   android.content.res.Resources.Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(`int[]`
>   attrs)
>
> Return a `TypedArray` holding the values defined by Theme which are
>   listed in attrs.
>
> Be sure to call `TypedArray.recycle()` when you are done with the array.

Comment: What happens, if not? E.g. because I leave the function scope?

Answer (score 2):

if you need it in the xml file, you can use something like this:

```
style="?android:attr/panelTextAppearance"
```

for example:

```
<TextView
    style="?android:attr/panelTextAppearance"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/paddingTop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/your_text"
    />
```

if you're using eclipse, control+click on the item, to see other possible values (a file attrs.xml will open).