# Android ActionBar: how to get its theme?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I know there are many built-in themes for ActionBar: Holo Light, Holo Dark, Holo Light with Dark ActionBar...

Is there any way to know, is the current theme of ActionBar is Dark or Light?

Comment: did you try [context.getTheme()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getTheme())

Comment: There are several methods belong to Theme but they're not what I need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9537629/1318946

Answer (score 0):

With suggest from Android developer community (Google+), I finally find there such method from HoloEverywhere source code: `ThemeManager.getThemeType(context)`

```
public static int getThemeType(Context context) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {
                R.attr.holoTheme
        });
        final int holoTheme = a.getInt(0, 0);
        a.recycle();
        switch (holoTheme) {
            case 1:
                return DARK;
            case 2:
                return LIGHT;
            case 3:
                return MIXED;
            case 4:
                return PreferenceManagerHelper.obtainThemeTag();
            case 0:
            default:
                return INVALID;
        }
    }
```