# Querying the background colour of an app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two basic UI designs for my Xamarin.Forms app, one for light backgrounds, and one for dark backgrounds. Basically, The icons change from white to black depending on the background colour. I have approximated the selection of these to whether the platform is iOS (light) or Android (dark). However, given the option for android users to use skins, I wondered if there was a way of finding out whether the phone actually had a light or dark background?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a platform specific dependency injection service for that (https://developer.xamarin.com/videos/cross-platform/accessing-native-features-through-the-dependency-service/).

On Android use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9537629/5064986

To get background color:

```
    const int TYPE_FIRST_COLOR_INT = 28;
    const int TYPE_LAST_COLOR_INT = 31;
    TypedValue a = new TypedValue();
    Theme.ResolveAttribute(Android.Resource.Attribute.WindowBackground, a, true);
    if (a.Type >= TYPE_FIRST_COLOR_INT && a.Type <= TYPE_LAST_COLOR_INT) {
        // windowBackground is a color
        int color = a.Data; // int representation of background color
    } else {
        // windowBackground is not a color, probably a drawable
        Drawable d = Resources.GetDrawable(a.ResourceId);
        // do something with it ... 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I access the background colour? Ideally without having to use a lookup table for each skin?