# Change Application Background Image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I want to change background image of my application when user select the image from setting activity, I set the background image using theme as:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/sunset</item>
</style>
```

Now how can I change the android:windowBackground via code.

Comment: You aren't asking a question. Also, what have you tried? Do you receive any errors?

Comment: @aneal I am trying to change the background image via code which is first set by XML shown above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

after some R&D and example, i got is to solve this issue you have to do as follow:

First create the Theme. (You have already created your Theme)

Then get The Theme at runTime and set the Background of that Theme as you want.

Then set the Theme as Application Theme.

Above steps is what you can do to get Change the Background of whole of your app.

For to getTheme and set the attribute value see this: [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052549/how-to-get-theme-attributes-values)

Also See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793183/access-resource-defined-in-theme-and-attrs-xml-android).

Comment: So what is the best way to follow to achieve my target with less efforts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't want to restrict user to select few Background Images, he can explore SD Card and select any image as its background

Comment: I haven't seen any way to set the background of a theme at run-time yet in any of your links. Same thing when I googled it. Could you be more precise and add some code example?

Comment: @ForceMagic: I don't know any method to set Application Background at runtime. but you can set the Background of individual activity. For that you can use:  getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(bg_path));

Comment: Then I'm not sure to understand how you would `Then get The Theme at runTime and set the Background of that Theme as you want.` since I haven't seen any way to set the background of a Theme.

Answer (score 1):

From your activity, call [getWindow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindow%28%29).[setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable drawable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) or [getWindow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindow%28%29).[setBackgroundDrawableResource(int resid)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setBackgroundDrawableResource%28int%29).